# Why Does My For Loop Iterate Incorrectly In C

Tags: c

So I'm kinda lost, I'm trying to make my own strstr function and just for debugging purposes I have a printf statement and since the string I'm looking for is "tea" it should output "t" "e" "a" but for some reason it keeps saying "t" "t" "e" "a". I'm really lost as to why. Could anybody help me?

```
char* substringSearch(char* haystack, char* needle, int i)
```

```
if (haystack[i] == needle[0])
{
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(needle); j++)
    {
        if (haystack[i] == needle[j])
        {
            printf("%c\n", needle[j]);
            counter++;
            i++;
        }   
            
    }
         
}
```

Comment: Can you flesh this out to a [mcve]?

Comment: The posted code can print each character of `needle` at most once. So wherever the answer to your question may lie, it is elsewhere in the code not posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will result incorrectly in case input strings is sequentially: 'i have ttea', 'tea'.
So in the first matched character 't' is gonna be printed and following by perfect matched characters 't','e','a'.
You should save your matched character in an array, and compare whole array with *needle to know if it matches or not.

Comment: The input I have though is "This tea is great!" So I don't know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You should, preferably, include a snippet that adheres to the [**reprox**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guidelines.

The code is too vague to discern any bugs at first glance,  best guess would be that the value passed to parameter *needle* contains a repeated pattern such as 'tt': maybe because of a typo, or it being badly constructed outside of the function.

Do me a favor and do a step-wise debug run on the function:

1. Set a breakpoint right when you call the function, then step-in.
2. Add watches to important values (or hover your mouse over if supported by your IDE).
3. Execute line by line the code encapsulated in the function.
4. Keep checking the values that variables have taken.
5. GOTO 3 until you find what makes the bug appear.

'Bookmark' all the cases you found the bug on, then post back which inputs you used, the output you received and a **complete snippet** of the function.

I recommend you check the pointers to the strings and the boundary of each one, maybe you are going out of bounds and are accessing contiguous memory blocks or even memory garbage, which is considered [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++).

Cheers!